# ASP classic: What determines character encoding for ADODB?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, asp-classic, adodb

If there is any input or output on an ASP page [this sort of thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21914278/2662901) works like a charm:

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBScript" CodePage = 65001 %>
<% 
  Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
  Response.CodePage = 65001
%>
```

But if it's an ASP page executing pure VBS and I pass a non-latin character string as a parameter to an MS SQL sproc via `Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")` then it's turned into a series of `?` characters somewhere between when the command is Executed and MS SQL puts it into a varchar column.

However, I do have one instance of IIS on which the same ASP pages will insert such strings into the database with UTF-8 encoding.  Since I can't find the IIS setting that allows that to work, how can I force an ADODB.Command Parameter value to be converted to UTF-8?

Comment: If you are passing UTF-8 encoded characters to SQL Server they should be being placed in an `NVARCHAR` column not a `VARCHAR`, that will explain the encoding mismatch you are encountering. Parameter wise you should be using a data type of `adVarWChar` or `adLongVarWChar` respectively.

Comment: @Lankymart - I'll test using that ADO data type flag right now.  I know the DB column *should* be an NVARCHAR, but it's a legacy system.  Any insight into [how the very same database and code could have received UTF-8-encoded strings when the ASP is run from a different IIS server](http://serverfault.com/q/796971/350508)?

Comment: Interesting question, is the same provider being used on both servers? It also depends entirely on what the page is doing i.e posting data from a form for example.

Comment: @Lankymart: All this particular sequence was doing was some REST via MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP and calling some sprocs.  I just posted the fix as an answer ... though the answer really raises more questions.  Maybe the biggest question is, "Where did I go wrong that I'm working on an ASP classic system?" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP character encoding can be a fickle thing.  In a codebase of 169 ASP files *one* had been saved with UTF-8-BOM encoding.  It was deployed to one machine but not the other.  All it contained was some VBS `FUNCTION` definitions.  But any ASP that included that file with BOM encoding was immediately rendered incapable of appending an ADODB.Command Parameter in UTF-8.  Instead it apparently decided – but only for ADODB.Command purposes, not for, say, JSON PUT over MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP objects – that everything that wasn't ASCII was `?`.

That's it: Save a codefile as UTF-8-BOM and ASP breaks.  Save it as UTF-8 it works again.

How can you discover that one of your 169 ASP files spread across a few dozen directories is saved using the "wrong" encoding?  I don't know.  I got lucky, happened to know where recent work had been done, and happened to check the file's encoding in Notepad++.

Is it just having two different encodings that confuses classic ASP?  I don't know, but [here's at least one other answer that suggests that BOM encoding causes problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33627535/2662901).